# Reload audio file from DB in JS

Tags: javascript

I press a button in browser:

```
function action() {
  var audio = new Audio("https://mydb.com/output.wav");
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
}
```

Then, I change my sound in DB with other button.

It changes in DB, but it does not reload in JS.

What can I do?

Thank you!

`audio.load();`

doesn't help